# Create a file with string while JSONArray iterates

Tags: java

I have the following JAVA Code and I need to save `String Atributos` in a .txt file while the code gets JSONObjects on the loop.

```
JSONObject JsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONObject Definition = (JSONObject) JsonObject.get("ScriptDefinition");
        JSONObject Map = (JSONObject) Definition.get("ScriptNameMap");
        JSONArray TestObjectArray = (JSONArray) Map.get("TestObject");
        Iterator<?> i = TestObjectArray.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            JSONObject Slide = (JSONObject) i.next();
            String Name = (String) Slide.get("Name");
            String Instance = (String) Slide.get("TO");
            String Atributos = Name + "," + Instance;               
            System.out.println(Atributos);}
```

output is:

`aceptar,GuiTestObject
jTextField,TextGuiSubitemTestObjec
login,TopLevelTestObject
login2,GuiTestObject`

How to get a file with this output?

Answer (score 0):

Write the data to a file.

```
FileWriter out = new FileWriter(new File(fileLocation));
out.append(Atributos);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: I only get to save  in  the .txt the last line `login2,GuiTestObject ` . ¿How can I to save all the output?

Comment: By making the call with the necessary data?  Do some research Turner.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PrintStream` like below

`String fileName = "D:\\Myfile.txt"
 PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
 System.setOut(out);
 System.out.println(Atributos);`

Comment: I only get to save in the .txt the last line `login2,GuiTestObject` . ¿How can I to save all the output? –